# What is difference between CDC, JRE, OSGi execution environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, cdc

In terms of Eclipse, what is the difference between CDC, JRE and OSGi execution environments? What are the consequences of using any one of above 3 execution environment at the time of creating new project in eclipse?

Comment: clearly non-opinion-based and not remotely subjective; the user is asking 'what does this menu option do?', which is on-topic.

Comment: CDC is the Eclipse C/C++ tool set.  If you're developing in C or C++, you'll use the Eclipse CDC.  JRE is the Java run time environment.  After you develop and package your Java application in a JAR, the JAR will run in the JRE.  If you're developing an Eclipse plug-in, you'll use the OSGi environment that Eclipse uses.

Comment: @soru The question is far more broad than that.

Comment: Thanks gilbert le blanc

Answer (score 2):

CDC is not related to C/C++ Tooling (that's the CDT), it is instead one of several specifications for the Java Runtime and language features you are targeting, specifically [Connected Device Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/tech/index-jsp-139293.html) (think embedded systems with less power than even the Raspberry Pi). See an explanation and list of the Execution Environments [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments#Standard_Execution_Environments).